# Can I get a Russian transit visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, russia, transit-visas

I need to apply for a transit visa to go outside the Russian airport (48 hours of layover). Due to shortage of time I cannot apply the transit visa in India. Does Russian government allow passenger to take transit visa from the airport itself ?

Passenger should have take visa if they even have to stay in Transit area for more than 24 hours. How do they apply?

Comment: Are you a Russian citizen or an Indian citizen ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Indian citizen